Why is low-level const of a reference not deduced?
When we use auto to deduce type of an object, top-level consts are ignored, for e.g.
const int i = 0; //i is top-level const
auto j = i; //j is an int

However, low-level consts are never ignored, e.g.
const int * ptr = nullptr //ptr is low-level const;
auto ptr2 = ptr; //ptr2 is also const int*

But when I define a low-level const reference, and use auto, it loses the const
int var;
const int &ref = var; //ref is low-level const reference
auto ref2 = ref; //ref2 is int! I had this previously as int&, which is wrong`

Why is this behavior?
Tried on VS2017 C++ compiler
Edit: Thanks for all the answers!
So auto doesn't deduce references https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/type-deduction-with-pointers-references-and-const/

Auto will not deduce references, read this : [https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/type-deduction-with-pointers-references-and-const/](Type deduction with pointers, references, and const). So you have to use auto& ref2 = ref. (If you would have looked carefully you would have seen ref2 is actually an int not even an int&

"//ref2 is int&!..." No it is not.

That's because there are no "top level" or "low level" const, there's only const. If you have a const object, there's no need for, let's say, a copy to be const as well. If you have a pointer to a const object, a copy of that pointer still points to the same const object. While, btw, a const pointer to a const object can be copied into a non-const pointer to the same const object...

@ChristianStieber " there are no "top level" or "low level" const..." No, you're wrong. There is indeed such a thing as top-level const and low-level const. Many good/great c++ books use that term.  The term is also there in the c++ standard. Where is the definition of top-level cv-qualifiers in the C++11 Standard?

You can verify that ref2 is not a reference (i.e. that it is a distinct variable of type int that is a copy of var) by comparing addresses (e.g. &ref == &var will be true, &ref2 == &var and &ref2 == &ref will both be false - indicating that ref and var are alternative/alias names of the same int, and ref2 is the name of another int.


const int is a value, when duplicating a value it is not sure you want it to be const, so auto will be deduced as an int. for example, the following won't be an error:

    const int v=1;
    int v1=v; // you can assign from const value to not const value


a pointer like const int* is a different thing: if the source is const you can't put a non-const pointer on it since you bypass the constness of it, therefor auto will have to save the constness. for example, the following will result the error:

    int arr[]={1,2,3};
    const int* a = arr;//you can add constness
    int* b=a;          //you can't remove constness

 
main.cpp:15:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
   15 |     int* b=a;
      |            ^
      |            |
      |            const int*


a reference is treated as a value after being created, so unless you specify it as auto&, it will be treated as a value, and will be an int


Because it just... makes sense?
You don't want to strip non-top-level constness from a pointer/reference because that would be unsafe (potentially letting you modify a const object, which is UB).
But when creating a copy (using auto without &/&&), you don't really care about the constness of the original object. If you e.g. have a function returning const T & (or god forbid const T), it doesn't make you any more likely to want a const copy of the return value, compared to a function returning just T or T &.

And as noted by @user12002570's in his answer, auto ref2 = ref; //ref2 is int&! - the comment here is wrong, the type is deduced as just int.


//ref2 is int&!

No, it is not because ref2 is actually an int.
auto here works by using the same mechanism as template argument deduction. Basically, the type is deduced from the initializer expression using the same mechanism as template argument deduction.
This means that when you wrote auto ref2 = ref;,the type of ref2 is exactly the type of the argument t in an imaginary template template<class T> void f(T t) if the function call f(ref) was compiled.
const int &ref = var;
auto ref2 = ref;

//the above behaves the same as the following
template<class T> void f(T t);
f(ref); //here also t is deduced as int


This also means that if you've to explicitly use operator & if you want the deduced type to be a reference type.
const int &ref = var;
auto &ref2 = ref;

//the above behaves as
template<class T> void f(T &t);

f(ref); //t is deduced as const int&


A reference of type T& behaves like an alias of a T object. Suppose you have a variable with a declared type of const int:
const int x = 1;

The name of the variable, x, can be used as an expression, which is an lvalue, and whose type is const int.
A reference to const int that is initialized to refer to x has the same properties as the original x when used in an expression:
const int& r = x;  // `r` is an expression which is an lvalue with type `const int`

So while the const in const int& is not top-level const in the type of the reference, it is top-level const in the type of the expression r, the same as how the const in the type of the expression x is top-level const.
